# EF Code First in many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, mapping, many-to-many

I have this classes:

```
public class User
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

DB table - **users**

```
public class Pet
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

DB table - **pets**

```
public class UsersPets
{
 public int UserId {get; set;}
 public int PetId {get; set;}
}
```

DB table - **users_pets**

To now I can get user's pets with linq. But how auto-mapping `User.Pets` without additionally Linq-queries in EF Code First?

Comment: check out my article on navigation properties here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first you will need to describe how these entities are related using navigation properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a plain many-to-many relation, you don't need an extra class, you can simply add two properties to your `User` and `Pet` classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }

    public User
    {
        Pets = new List<Pet>();
    }
}

public class Pet
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Pet
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

Notice that the `Pets` and `Users` collections are `virtual`. This enables lazy loading to prevent loading the pets of a user when you don't need them.

```
// Pets not loaded
var user = db.Users.Find(1);

// This loads the pets for the user (lazy loading)
foreach (var pet in user.Pets)
{
    ...
}

// This immediately loads the pets for the user (eager loading)
var user2 = db.Users.Include(u => u.Pets).SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just change your classes to:

```
public class User
{
    public User(){
        Pets = new HashSet<Pet>();
    }

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Pet> Pets;
}

public class Pet
{
    public Pet(){
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public ICollection<User> Users;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EF creates this table for you, you shouldnt do it in your model. So :

```
public class User
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name  {get; set;}
public ICollection<Pet> Pets  {get; set;}
} 

public class Pet
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The additional table will be created in the database and you can access the Pets collection for the User entity in code.